# Inheritance with generics and nested record helper

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, record, helper

I'm trying to do the following in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but the compiler return the message "F2084 Internal Error: AV0A785E48-R000000-10-0":

```
TMyType = (mtValue1, mtValue2);

TMyBaseClass = class
private
  FMyType: TMyType;
public
  property MyType: TMyType read FMyType write FMyType;
end;

TMyClass = class(TMyBaseClass)
private
  FOtherField: Integer;
public
  property OtherField: Integer read FOtherField write FOtherField;
end;

TMyBaseProcess1<T: TMyBaseClass> = class
strict private
  FMyClass: T;
strict protected
  type
    TMyTypeHelper = record Helper for TMyType
    public
      function ToString: string;
    end;
public
  constructor Create(AMyClass: T);
  procedure DoSomething;
end;

TMyProcess1 = class(TMyBaseProcess1<TMyClass>)
end;

TMyBaseProcess2<T: TMyBaseClass> = class
strict private
  FMyClass: T;
strict protected
  type
    TMyTypeHelper = record Helper for TMyType
    public
      function ToInteger: Integer;
    end;
public
  constructor Create(AMyClass: T);
  procedure DoSomethingElse;
end;

TMyProcess2 = class(TMyBaseProcess2<TMyClass>)
end;
```

The helper in TMyBaseProcess1 is totally different of the helper in TMyBaseProcess2. I can separate the helper and the class without problems. I only want to know why I can't leave them together.

Anyone knows what is the problem? Can I use generics, nested record helper and inheritance this way?

Comment: Compiler defect. Submit a bug report. Record helpers on nested types of generics look odd tbh.

Comment: Can't you directly write the implementation without using record helpers?

Comment: David Heffernan. Thanks for the help. My example is only for demonstration. The real situation is a bit different.

Comment: Alberto Miola: Sorry for the example. It's just a test case, not the real situation. In the real case I can't  implement directly in the record. I will change the example for a better one.

Comment: For sure it's a compiler defect, ICE always is. But the code should probably not compile anyway. Helpers and generic instantiation really make no sense. Write the code without that construct.

Comment: *Internal Error* means the compiler encountered an issue it couldn't deal with; the error message only makes sense to those who have access to the source code, and that's not us. Your options are to either submit a bug report (along with **actual code** that will allow EMBT to reproduce it) or to change your code until it goes away. I'd agree with @David; helpers and generic instantiation aren't a valid pairing.

Comment: Ken White: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not have **two** helpers pointing to same class type
in your case **TMyType**

from docs..

> You can define and associate multiple helpers with a single type. However, only **zero or one** helper applies in any specific location in source code.

use helper outside that classes

```
TMyTypeHelper = record Helper for TMyType
    public
      function ToInteger: Integer;
      function ToString: string; 
    end;
```

Comment: But I'm using only one helper at a time. It's not possible?